# Unable to run mocha tests on firebase-functions, [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/encoder' is not defined by "exports"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, mocha.js

When I try and run a Mocha test script in a Firebase functions directory, I get this error:

```
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/encoder' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/[...redacted...]/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/package.json
```

I am using Node 12 and my devDependencies are:

```
{
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.3",
    "mocha": "^8.4.0"
}
```

Comment: Can you try running this command: `npm install -g firebase-tools`, then recheck your test script.

Comment: No change in result after running that @RJC.

Comment: Here's a [Github link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/942) that discusses this issue. You can check [this comment](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/942#issuecomment-899710653) that fixed the error that is similar to yours.

Answer (score 3):

Install Firebase function test

```
npm i firebase-functions-test@0.3.2
```